# Call a R function in OpenCPU with file arguments

Tags: javascript, r, opencpu

I want to let a user call a custom R function with custom arguments, using a web-based interface. Uploading local files for use should be possible.

I tried to implement this using [OpenCPU](https://www.opencpu.org/) which worked fine until now. The user's code is packed into a `ocpu.Snippet` and passed together with the arguments `args` into

```
ocpu.call(
    'do.call',
    {
        'what': snippet,
        'args': args
    },
    session => /* processing of return value and console output */
);
```

This works fine for all argument types I've worked with so far.

Now that I'm testing the upload of files, I have found out the following:

1. The [JavaScript wrapper](https://github.com/Y0hy0h/opencpu.js/blob/master/opencpu.js) (forked to remove annoying alerts) only detects files if they are on the upmost level (like `snippet` and `args` in the example above). This means that since my `args` *contain* a file object (`args = { file: File }`) they are not detected when using the call above. However, calling `ocpu.call('read.csv', args, ...)` works, since now the wrapper detects `file: File`.
2. OpenCPU [only allows file uploads using `multipart/form-data`](https://www.opencpu.org/api.html#api-arguments). As far as I have learned, a nested file as I have in my original call is not representable in this format.
3. Instead of using `do.call` I could write a custom R function to use, which allows for some way of providing used files as "first-order" arguments and then somehow passes them to the provided function.

So I'm stuck, since I don't know how to write such a function and I really wonder if there is better way to call a custom function and control its arguments remotely. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around a bit, I found that the function was relatively easy to write:

```
functionCall <- function(func, ...) {
  return(do.call(func, list(...)))
}
```

After making that function available in OpenCPU, it can be called using

```
args = {
  func: snippet,
  x: firstArg,
  y: secondArg,
  // arbitrarily many args
}

opencpu.call(
  'functionCall',
  openCpuArgs,
  callback
);
```

I tested this with a `snippet` that calls `read.csv` and it successfully printed its content instead of returning an error.